# Can input value artribute be defined as empty?

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following code:

```
<input type = "Text" value="" class="MyClass"/>
```

Can value be declared as empty?

In the chrome debugger, it appears like the following, which doesn't look correct

[image]

However the onkeypress event is never fired. I'm guessing it's because the "value" attribute looks a bit weird and is causing it to break, but I dont know for sure. This works in firefox.

Comment: `value` is same as `value=""` for chrome representation, to not waste space

Comment: That's perfectly fine, value is equal to value=""

Comment: Yes you can, and it will not create any impact on it

Comment: @Hacketo in chrome, in firefox, in United States and in Spain. You can put all attributes you want without value, and it's valid :)

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude OP defined it as `value=""` in the HTML code, so chrome removed it when displayed in the DOM, as it also removed the end of the `input` tag `/` . Not saying that `value` is not valid

Comment: @Hacketo yeah, I am understand what you say. In your non-edited comment you said "in chrome", and it's for this because I tell you in all browsers and countries :) It's a joke, sorry if you are molested.

Comment: Note that you can also remove `value=""` as the input has already an empty `value` propertie

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude Yes, I messed up with the comma, I wanted to say : "Chrome removed it to not waste space in the DOM representation"

Comment: As has been said, the `value` definition is not an issue. Perhaps your `CheckCursor` function not being executed is due to a typo? (lower case c?) It works fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/j0su6xhh/ Or maybe you're expecting it to fire _after_ the key was pressed, in which case you should use `onkeyup`?

Comment: @NeilP There is some behavior when the input has a `0px` width or height that do not fire events in some browser. Could you add more details about this input ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can.

```
var myInput = document.getElementById('ourInput');

if(myInput.value.length == 0)
myInput.value = "Empty";
```

Note: myInput.value =="" will too.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, and it will not create any impact on it 
Try this

```
$("input").keypress(function(){
    //do your stuff
});
```

Or

```
<input type="text" onkeypress="myFunction()">

function myFunction() {
    alert("You pressed a key inside the input field");
}
```